# Retrieve specific value from Hive Box

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-hive

In my app, I am using Hive to store data locally. My box is called "favorites" and I managed to store the data in the box with this code:

```
_save() { 
  final recipeData = Recipe(
   title:  widget.recipeDocument['title'],
   id:  widget.recipeDocument['id'],
   price: widget.recipeDocument['price'],
   url: widget.recipeDocument['url'],
   servings: widget.recipeDocument['servings'],
   calories: widget.recipeDocument['calories'],
   carbs: widget.recipeDocument['carbs'],
   protein: widget.recipeDocument['protein'],
   fat: widget.recipeDocument['fat'],
   ingredients: widget.recipeDocument['ingredients'],
   instructions: widget.recipeDocument['instructions'],);

   print('Generated recipeData final $recipeData');
   String json =jsonEncode(recipeData);
   print('Generated json $json');
   
   final box = Hive.box('favorites'); //<- get an already opened box, no await necessary here
  // save recipe information
final Id = widget.recipeDocument['id'];
  box.put(Id,json);
```

On my favorite page, I want to display the title and price in a ListView.
I get data from the box like this:

```
 body:  ValueListenableBuilder(
          
          valueListenable: Hive.box('favorites').listenable(),
          builder: (context, box, child) {
            var box = Hive.box('favorites');
            List post = List.from(box.values);
            print('List is $post');
```

The list contains the following:

```json
[
  {
    "url": "http for URL",
    "title": "Bananabread",
    "price": "0,77",
    "calories": "234",
    "carbs": "12",
    "fat": "1",
    "id": "1",
    "protein": "34",
    "servings": 1,
    "ingredients": [
      "2 bananas",
      "30 g flour",
      "2 eggs"
    ],
    "instructions": [
      "1. mix banana and egg.",
      "2. add flour.",
      "3. bake and enjoy"
    ]
  }
]
```

Let's say I only want to retrieve the title and price from that. How do I do so?

I tried this:

```
return ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('This shows favorites'),
              ...post.map(
                (p) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(p[1]),
                  trailing: Text(p[2]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
```

But this only returns "U" and "R"...so the letters from the word URL, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You are accessing the key of the map in the list.

```
 return ListView(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
  children: <Widget>[
    Text('This shows favorites'),
    ...post.map(
      (p) => ListTile(
        title: Text(p['url'].toString()),
        trailing: Text(p['title'].toString()),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: I also tried this before, but this gives the error: The following _TypeError was thrown building ValueListenableBuilder<Box<dynamic>>(dirty, state:
_ValueListenableBuilderState<Box<dynamic>>#c01ae):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Comment: @NisiCH Can you post the full code here?